# Is there a way to see/recover the deleted test run results from TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2018

The on-premise TFS installation that we have in our organization was upgraded from 2013 to 2015 and now finally 2018. However, recently we started noticing that the test run results from older test cases were being automatically deleted and the test cases were being set to Active.

I found out through this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/test-result-data-retention-with-team-foundation-server-2015/#1-team-project-level-test-retention-policy-to-clean-up-test-result-data-by-age) that TFS 2015 Update 1 introduced a retention policy and for any older projects it was Never Delete and for any projects created after the Update 1 upgrade was 365 days. And sure enough, the only  projects that had data deleted were created after 2015.

Now, we currently do not have a proper TFS admin so we are trying to find out a solution to see if it was possible to recover that deleted test run data or is it gone from the system as well? I have not seen anything on the internet that could help and only articles that I find all link to the above MS page.

So, is it still possible to somehow recover those results? Or are they lost forever?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to see/recover the deleted test run results from TFS 2018?

I am afraid there is no such a way to recover the deleted test run results from TFS 2018.

Accordig to the document [Delete test artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/delete-test-artifacts?view=azure-devops):

> **We only support permanent deletion of test artifacts** such as test
> plans, test suites, test cases, shared steps and shared parameters.
> Deleted test artifacts won't appear in the recycle bin and cannot be
> restored. Deletion of test artifacts not only deletes the selected
> test artifact but also all its associated child items such as child
> test suites, test points across all configurations, testers (the
> underlying test case work item doesn't get deleted), **test results
> history**, and other associated history.

So, the deleted test result will be permanently deleted, could not be recovered.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Leo! That is quite unfortunate that the policy is auto-set to 365 days for newer projects. We seem to have lost a good chunk of data by now.


Anyways, we are still looking around for ways to recover this data. We do have backups of the TFS DBs. And upon closer inspection, these DBs also have TestRun, TestResults and similar tables. We were wondering whether exporting the data of these tables from the backups and importing it in the existing TFS DB tables make any difference? Will we be able to see the restore reflected in the web client?